# How to use a form's input, coded in JS, to process it with a CGI Script?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, apache

A friend of mine is developing a website and ask me for help. I know really little of web development but i do know my ways around c++. Thing is, the web has a form that can be filled by people that want to be contacted. We wanted that the input user provided in the form  is written into a .csv file  which could be open in excel. Also i was trying to do it on an apache server, running on my machine(not sure if apache will be the actual webserver for the finished website). Im afraid i could be asking the wrong question, or overseeing something really simple. I need to know whats the easiest way to take that input and process it with a C++ script. Maybe even avoid the cgi script and doing it on JS ? Sorry for the vague question, need to solve this by monday!

Comment: `C++ script` - never seen one of those - you sure you know your way around C++?

Comment: In general, server admins are very cautious about executing C++ executables from unknown people on their server.  Have you though about other alternatives such as PHP?

Comment: Sorry!! english is not my first language, and never coded in an interpreted language... Always thought script was a synonym of code! I will look at a PHP alternative! thanks